# AngularJS Synchronous call

Tags: angularjs, http

In easily understandable pseudo code, I have this in AngluarJS. It is supposed to do a or b or both when we have c. The problem I have now is that the calls are asynchronously called and my data is screwed up.

```
if(a || c) {
    $http.get("path1");
}
if(b || c) {
    $http.get("path2");
}
```

As you see, I can't put the second GET into the .succes method of the first call because of the if statement.
I could fiddle around with a function where the second get is listen in, but I think there should be a proper way to do this.

Comment: may I ask why your data is screwed up when the call is async? I mean is it the order of the calls ? or you need to know when both are finished?

Comment: After looking for hours I have found my problem. I was misled by a filter in Angluar which returns an item with id 17 while looking for id 7. So my item with id 7 was overwritten. That made my data look screwed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just hold of the promise object, that might be returned from the first `a || c` check ajax. If that satisfied/unsatisfied `$q.when` will resolve the promise by checking the `promise` value.

The reason behind using `$q.when` is if the promise will undefined then also `.then` function of `$q.when` going to resolve promise. [**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/Q2jMG/)

And if `promise` will have promise object then it will wait till that promise gets resolved.

**Code**

```
var promise;
if(a || c) {
    promise = $http.get("path1");
}
$q.when(promise).then(function(response){
    if(b || c) {
       promise = $http.get("path2");
     }
}, function(error){
    //error
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this miss the case 'b' alone? 'b' would have `promise` undefined and therefore the `$q.when()`-path would never been taken, right?

Comment: @JohannesJander if promise is `undefined` then also `.then` success part get called or if the `promise` has promise object. then it will wait till promise gets resolved..

Comment: Good to know that the B will be executed then. Is the function(error) mandatory?

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire I just added that..so that if you have any web logging work on error. you could do that from there. Thanks :)

Comment: Although this didin't solve my problem (problem is somewhere else), it clearly answers what I was looking for. I now understand promisses better, which is a big plus! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Make your calls in a Factory

I don't fully see why you have a problem but maybe a separation of concerns will help you to see the full picture.

```
.factory('yourFactory', function($http){
    getFirstThing: function(){
        return $http.get("path1");
    },
    getSecondThing: function(){
        return $http.get("path2");
    }
});
```

## Add the if statement to your controller

```
if(a || c) {
   yourFactory.getTheFirstThing;
}
if(b || c) {
   yourFactory.getTheSecondThing;
}
```

Comment: How will this make `$http` calls synchronously?

Comment: I can't work with a factory since I am touching existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `if` statement make a problem?

```
if(c)
    $http.get("path1").success(function(data){
        $http.get("path2")
    })
else
{
    if(a)
        $http.get("path1");
    else
        $http.get("path2");
}
```